# Include finished website in Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.4

I just started working with a CMS and I decided to use Joomla. So my thoughts were, that I can use those functions that Joomla provides for my already existing site, but when I configure Joomla, there is already a site with an easy design.

So my question is, whether I can include my already existing site and replace the default design from Joomla?

I appreciate every help and comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you decide to adopt a CMS, you must embrace its definitions, features and methodology. Otherwise, you are creating some hybrid site.

To migrate a site to Joomla, you must create or implement a template for the site design, define a navigational structure and migrate the content to Joomla items.

In other words, there is no way to "drop" a site into Joomla.

Comment: Anibal is 200% right on spot! If you choose CMS then you use it the way it was planned and programmed. If you don't want to do that, then you just don't use CMS. Even though there are some ways to include pure HTML site in Joomla either through iframe or by building specific template just for it, but is much, much better to use Joomla the way it is intended.

Comment: It seems I'm the one gulty for '6,007 ways to say thanks to Joomla!'... Cheers mate!!! :-)

Comment: YES! You are ! :-D